# Multiple 401 Angular Token Interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jwt, angular-http-interceptors

I have created a Token Interceptor in Angular which I use to refresh my JWT token.
Unfortunately, I don't know why, several calls fail (error 401), and when the interceptor retrieves the new token, only the last one that failed is redone.
This means that it misses some calls and my UI is not filling properly.

I try to leave you a few pieces of code and a photo.

[image]

And this is my token interceptor:

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, filter, switchMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { G3SnackType } from '@cgm/g3-component-lib';
import { G3SnackbarService } from '@cgm/g3-component-lib';

import { AuthFacade } from '@g3p/auth-shell/store/auth.facade';
import { AuthService } from '@g3p/auth-shell/services/auth.service';
import { ITokenError, ITokenErrorModal } from '@g3p/auth-shell/interfaces/token-error.interface';
import { LoggerService } from '@g3p/shared/error-handler/logger.service';
import { SessionStorageJwtService } from '@g3p/auth-shell/services/session-storage-jwt.service';
import { Token } from '@g3p/auth-shell/interfaces/token.interface';
import { TokenErrorType } from '@g3p/auth-shell/interfaces/token-error.enum';
import { TokenErrorComponent } from '@g3p/auth-shell/components/token-error/token-error.component';

const tokenErrorModalSettings = {
  width: '25.75rem',
  height: '15.5rem',
  disableClose: true,
  autoFocus: false,
  data: {} as ITokenErrorModal
};

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private isRefreshing = false;
  private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<Token> = new BehaviorSubject<Token>(null);

  constructor(
    private authFacade: AuthFacade,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private loggerService: LoggerService,
    private router: Router,
    private sessionStorageJwtService: SessionStorageJwtService,
    private snackbarService: G3SnackbarService,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
  ) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    let token: Token = {} as Token;
    this.sessionStorageJwtService.getToken().subscribe(t => (token = t));

    let refreshToken = '';
    this.sessionStorageJwtService.getRefreshToken().subscribe(t => (refreshToken = t));

    const path = request.url.split('/');
    if (
      path.includes('assets') ||
      path.includes('workstationregistration') ||
      (this.router.url.includes('rolespermission') && path.includes('users')) ||
      (this.router.url.includes('/auth') && path.includes('token'))
    ) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
        if ((error.error as ITokenError).error_description.includes(TokenErrorType.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED)) {
          return this.handle401Error(request, next, refreshToken);
        }
        if ((error.error as ITokenError).error_description.includes(TokenErrorType.INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN)) {
          this.showSnackbarTokenError(this.translateService.instant('content.invalid-refresh-token'));
        }
        if ((error.error as ITokenError).error_description.includes(TokenErrorType.CANNOT_CONVERT_ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
          this.showSnackbarTokenError(this.translateService.instant('content.cannot-convert-access-token'));
        }
        if ((error.error as ITokenError).error_description === TokenErrorType.USER_LOGGED_INTO_ANOTHER_WORKSTATION) {
          this.showModalTokenError(this.translateService.instant('content.user-logged-into-another-workstation'));
        }
        if ((error.error as ITokenError).error_description === TokenErrorType.USER_DELETED) {
          this.showModalTokenError(this.translateService.instant('content.user-deleted'));
        }
        if ((error.error as ITokenError).error_description === TokenErrorType.USER_CLAIMS_CHANGED) {
          this.showModalTokenError(this.translateService.instant('content.user-claims-changed'));
        }
        if ((error.error as ITokenError).error_description.includes(TokenErrorType.TECHNICAL_LOGOUT)) {
          this.showModalTokenError(this.translateService.instant('content.technical-logout'));
        }
      }
      return throwError(error);
    }));
  }

  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler, rToken: string) {
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      if (rToken && rToken !== '') {
        const body = new URLSearchParams();
        body.set('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
        body.set('refresh_token', rToken);

        return this.authService.fetchToken$(body).pipe(
          switchMap((newToken: Token) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;

            this.sessionStorageJwtService.setToken(newToken);
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(newToken);

            return next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, newToken));
          }),
          catchError((err) => {
            this.isRefreshing = false;

            this.authFacade.logout();
            return throwError(err);
          })
        );
      }

      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token !== null),
        take(1),
        switchMap((token) => next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, token)))
      );
    }
  }

  private addTokenHeader(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: Token) {
    return request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.access_token}`) });
  }

  private showSnackbarTokenError(message: string) {
    this.snackbarService.open(message, 5000, G3SnackType.Error);
    return this.authFacade.logout();
  }

  private showModalTokenError(message: string) {
    tokenErrorModalSettings.data.errorMessage = message;

    if (this.dialog.openDialogs.length < 1) {
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TokenErrorComponent, tokenErrorModalSettings);

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
        if (data?.errorMessage !== '') {
          return this.authFacade.logout();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

export const authInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

Comment: Do you have any other method (to get the `token`) than `this.sessionStorageJwtService.getToken()`? it's better to be `sync` one

Comment: @Amer Thanks for the reply. Btw no, that service in the only way to get the token.

Comment: I know, but does it provide any other property/function to get the `token` as a string directly, not as an observable?

Comment: @Amer No, I return an Observable because the Token is an object, and I prefer to do in this way. Do you think to change it?

Comment: I think it's better here to return the string `token` as a string, to be injected into the request directly.

Comment: In your code you're subscribing to token observable but you don't wait or inject it to the request.

Comment: @Amer Ok I’ll try and I’ll let you know! Thanks for now :)

Comment: I will add my answer about the refresh token taking into consideration that you will change the `token` observable with string. Is that okay for you?

Comment: @Amer Yeah for sure!

Comment: @Amer I tried but I didn't solve... Same problem.

Comment: Check my answer, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change the interceptor to something like the following:

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
  // 1 >>>> This should return the token as string to be injected to the requests directly
  const token: string = this.sessionStorageJwtService.getToken();

  // 2 >>>> Move this part to the handle401Error method
  // let refreshToken = "";
  // this.sessionStorageJwtService.getRefreshToken().subscribe((t) => (refreshToken = t));

  const path = request.url.split('/');
  if (
    path.includes('assets') ||
    path.includes('workstationregistration') ||
    (this.router.url.includes('rolespermission') && path.includes('users')) ||
    (this.router.url.includes('/auth') && path.includes('token'))
  ) {
    return next.handle(request);
  }

  // 3 >>>> Inject the token into the request header
  request = this.addTokenHeader(request, token);

  return next.handle(request).pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
        if (
          (error.error as ITokenError).error_description.includes(
            TokenErrorType.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRED
          )
        ) {
          return this.handle401Error(request, next);
        }
        // Handle the other errors here...
      }
      return throwError(error);
    })
  );
}

private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  if (!this.isRefreshing) {
    this.isRefreshing = true;
    // Set the refreshTokenSubject to null so that subsequent API calls will wait until the new token has been retrieved
    this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

    // 4 >>>> Chain the getRefreshToken with the fetchToken$ observables like the following:
    return this.sessionStorageJwtService.getRefreshToken().pipe(
      switchMap((rToken) => {
        if (!!rToken) {
          const body = new URLSearchParams();
          body.set('grant_type', 'refresh_token');
          body.set('refresh_token', rToken);
          return this.authService.fetchToken$(body);
        }

        throwError('Refresh token invalid');
      }),
      switchMap((newToken: Token) => {
        // When the call to refreshToken completes we reset the isRefreshing to false
        // for the next time the token needs to be refreshed
        if (newToken) {
          this.sessionStorageJwtService.setToken(newToken);
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(newToken);

          return next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, newToken));
        }

        throwError('Refresh token invalid');
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        this.authFacade.logout();
        return throwError(err);
      }),
      finalize(() => {
        this.isRefreshing = false;
      })
    );
  } else {
    // 5 >>>> Move this return to this block instead of above one, to be returned if the toke refresh is still on-progress
    return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
      filter((token) => token !== null),
      take(1),
      switchMap((token) => next.handle(this.addTokenHeader(request, token)))
    );
  }
}
```

The interceptor you're trying to use has some logical errors, like:

- It doesn't inject the fetched token into the request, which should be injected to authenticate the request correctly. It's better to return the current token as a string to be injected directly into the request.
- It call the `getRefreshToken` to get the refresh token, but you didn't wait for it to complete. But it should be moved to the `handle401Error` method and chained with the `this.authService.fetchToken$(body)` observable.
- It returns the `refreshTokenSubject` from the wrong block.