# How can I run an Async Function every time my Angular Service is hit?

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I use an Angular service currently for all of my backend API calls. These API calls must send a token as part of their Authorization header. In order to verify I have a valid accessToken I need to check it and possibly refresh it if it has expired.

I am using the latest Amplify / Congito for my authentication.

Based on what I have search so far the best way to get the token as well as refresh the accessToken if expired is to run the following:

```js
    async handleToken () {
      try {
        const cognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
        const currentSession = cognitoUser.signInUserSession;
        cognitoUser.refreshSession(currentSession.refreshToken, (err, session) => {
          return session.accessToken.jwtToken
        });
      } catch (e) {
      }
    }
```

This will return the current or newly refreshed accessToken to send.

My issue is I do not know how I can make sure to call this before every API call to make sure I send the latest token.

After searching more I found that this cannot be achieved via OnInit or in the constructor.

Here is an example of an API call.

```js
getCustomerList(): Observable<CustomerList[]> {
  this.handleToken();
  const url = hosturl +'c_l';
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': ls  || '{}'
    }),
    withCredentials: true,
    params: {
     'clientid': clientid
    }
  };
  return this._http.get(url, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return <CustomerList[]> res;
    }),
    catchError(err => throwError(this.handleError(err))),
  );
}
```

Note this will run the handleToken correctly, but it is not async due to the function calling it not using await.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you need to call this function on every API call, instead of storing the `token` in the `localStorage` and getting it from there to inject it into every API call. Anyway, you can create your own interceptor (that inspects and transform HTTP requests from your application to a server), then inject the `token` into the requests' header like the following:

```js
// import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
// import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Use RxJS `from` function to convert `Promise` to an `Observable`:
    return from(this.handleToken()).pipe(
      // Use RxJS `switchMap` operator to map the token's Observable to the next.handle one:
      switchMap((token) => {
        // Inject the token into the request's header, and pass it to the next request handler:
        return next.handle(
          req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`),
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }

  // Update the handleToken function to return a `Promise`:
  handleToken(): Promise<string> {
    return Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then((cognitoUser) =>
      cognitoUser.refreshSession(
        cognitoUser.signInUserSession.refreshToken,
        (err, session) => {
          return session.accessToken.jwtToken;
        }
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Read more about creating your own interceptor here: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: I would much prefer the option you mentioned. That is what I started off trying to do. The issue is that when my accessToken expires a user can send an API request with an expired accessToken which result in an error. I am going this route to ensure that I am sending a refreshed token.

Comment: You can handle the error in the interceptor also and then send the request again with the valid token after refreshing it. Check my answer here about the same case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69232543/15159603